# test app on 64bit windows

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit

I don't have 64bit windows, and i have to develop app for 64bit windows.

I have downloaded and installed virtual pc

i develop on windows xp 32bit, vista 32bit and win7 32bit

How to i develop a 32bit compatable application?

[EDIT]
Am developing using visual studio 6 & 2005, Borland c++ 7. And i havent seen 64bit versions of this softwares

Comment: You can try to use vmware... But you should not only test on x64. You should/must compile on it. Otherwise you need to do a cross-compile. Please specify your dev env.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way around getting a 64-bit version of Windows (can also be a VM running on top of 32-bit Windows).

Comment: If you do not have a 64-bit compiler, then you cannot produce 64-bit applications.  However, most 32-bit applications will run on 64-bit OSes just fine.  You only need to compile a 64-bit application if you explicitally need to access the 64-bit features of the OS, such as 4GB+ memory addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run a 64-bit application, you will need a 64-bit OS *and* 64-bit hardware.  You can't run a 64-bit guest on a host with 32-bit hardware.

You can build a 64-bit application with Visual Studio 2005.  I do not know about other IDE's you mention.  If I remember correctly, you have to choose to install the 64-bit tools when installing VS2005.  I seem to recall that they do not get installed by default (but memory may be failing me).  Once the 64-bit application is built, though, you cannot run it on the 32-bit machine.

Comment: what do you mean 64bit hardware? I cannot install 64bit windows on my compaq Evo D510 SFF

Comment: @Smith, the underlying chipset must provide 64-bit support. A quick google search seems to indicate that the PC you mention has the Intel 845G chipset, which was released in 2002.  It seems unlikely that it supports 64-bit.

Comment: "You can't run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host.": It is important here to distinguish between hardware support an OS bitness. You can run a 64-bit VM on top of a 32-bit OS if you have a 64-bit CPU, which almost all current CPU's are (see http://www.vmware.com/products/server/faqs.html).